# Powershell last logon query. Help setting up array to go thought all my domain controllers

Tags: powershell, domaincontroller

This script below works, but every attempt I make to have it cycle through all my domain controllers fail. How do I add a array to go through all these OUs on all my domain controllers. Thanks in advance!

```
$OUs= “OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=All Users,DC=domain,DC=local",
"OU=Test2,OU=Test2,OU=Test2,OU=All Users,OU=Test2,DC=domain,DC=local",
"OU=Test3,OU=Test3,OU=Test3,OU=All Users,OU=Test3,DC=domain,DC=local",
"OU=test4,OU=test4,OU=test4,OU=All Users,OU=test4,DC=domain,DC=local", 
"OU=Test5,OU=test5,OU=Test5,OU=All Users,OU=test5,DC=domain,DC=local”

$OUs | ForEach-Object 
  {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -SearchBase $_ -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | 
      Where-Object {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}
  } | 
  Sort LastLogonDate | 
  Format-Table -Property Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName | 
  Out-String
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  When I ran that it cycled through each OU, but obviously failed because it doesn't exist in my domain.

Comment: No error on my script. I am just not sure how to add a second array with my domain controllers and add that second array to the working script successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Below you have now an array of your OUs. Please try whether that works for you now.

```
$OUs= @(
  “OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=Test1,OU=All Users,DC=domain,DC=local",
  "OU=Test2,OU=Test2,OU=Test2,OU=All Users,OU=Test2,DC=domain,DC=local",
  "OU=Test3,OU=Test3,OU=Test3,OU=All Users,OU=Test3,DC=domain,DC=local",
  "OU=test4,OU=test4,OU=test4,OU=All Users,OU=test4,DC=domain,DC=local", 
  "OU=Test5,OU=test5,OU=Test5,OU=All Users,OU=test5,DC=domain,DC=local”
)
```

I would also suggest to break your line after every pipe in order to cut the line. That makes it far easier to read for you, plus your colleagues.

```
$OUs | ForEach-Object 
  {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -SearchBase $_ -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | 
      Where-Object {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}
  } | 
  Sort LastLogonDate | 
  Format-Table -Property Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName | 
  Out-String
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. The script I posted works. However due to the Last-Logon-Timestamp replication the time can be off up to 14 days. I want to also search all domains controllers to get the most accurate logon time.

Answer (score 0):

You mention cycling through your domain controllers, but then you go on to ask about OUs. I suspect you want DC's, because each DC might have a different Last Logon Time for the user.

You can omit the -SearchBase and search all OU's, if you're looking to get this data for all users.

```
$Domains = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * #Note, this shows all DCs- you may have some without ADWS Installed, which won't handle the WHERE. 
foreach ($domain in $Domains) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Server $domain -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate |
        Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} |
             Export-CSV -Path 'UsersNotRecentlyLoggedIn.CSV' -Append
}
```

If you only want one DC, but all OUs

```
$Domains = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service ADWS 
foreach ($domain in $Domains) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Server $domain -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate |
        Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} |
             Export-CSV -Path 'UsersNotRecentlyLoggedIn.CSV' -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. What I am trying to do is generate a report for all users listed in those specific OU's that havenet logged into the past 7 days. The reason why I want to search all domain controllers too, is because the Last-Logon-Timestamp is approximate and depending on replication be off by about 14 days. I thought searching all domain controllers will give me a more accurate report.

Comment: Ah- combine the two then. :-) My top one gives you all DC's because of the potential difference in Last Logon Timestamp, although the specific why we're doing it requires ADWS to be installed on your DCs- not sure if you have it installed on all of them in your domain?

Comment: ADWS is not installed. I'll have to look into that.